# Rails: Allow user to switch between different views using selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I allow users to switch between different views of the same content using a selection menu. For example look at the right hand side of http://railscasts.com/. You can switch between list view, table view and grid thumbnail view. What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set up a partial for each view, and either use `session` to store the preference or simply use `params`.

```
def index
  # ... code here
  @partial = params[:view] || "default" # "grid", "list", etc.
end
```

In `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render @partial %>
```

Then you would save each view partial in the controller's views folder, e.g. `_grid.html.erb`, `_list.html.erb`, and `_default.html.erb`

**EDIT**

In response to a comment on this (now five-year-old) answer, I am rescinding/amending my original advice. It's never a good idea to pass unverified params to `render`, because it has the potential to expose arbitrary data from your filesystem. Would instead recommend a whitelisting method:

```
def index
  @partial = whitelisted_partial || 'default'
end

def whitelisted_partial
  %w(grid list).detect { |str| str == params[:view] }
end
```

And in more direct response to the comment:

```
render partial: @partial, locals: { ... }
```

Comment: What if I want to pass a local in the partial?

Comment: Since this very old question was resurrected, I'm rescinding my original advice. Don't ever accept a param as an argument to `render`, or use a whitelist to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and declarative response.