# Rails switching between different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I allow users to switch between different views using a selection menu without using javascript toggle. Something like [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/map-list-toggle/#map-page) where I can switch between map and list views. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773161/rails-allow-user-to-switch-between-different-views-using-selection) and came up with the following.

user_controller.rb

```
@partial = params[:view] || "map" || "list"
```

index.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to "Map"%>
  <%= link_to "List"%>
  <%= render @partial %>
```

I have two view partials, `_map.html.erb` and `_list.html.erb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to make `link_to`s with the appropriate params.

```
<%= link_to "Map", page_path(view: "map") %>
```

This will load the map partial.